# When is a graph morphism a regular embedding?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, curves-and-surfaces, complete-intersection

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite morphism, where $X$ is an affine, non-singular curve and $Y$ is an affine, non-singular surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Denote by $\Gamma_f \subset X \times Y$ the graph of the morphism $f$. When is $\Gamma_f$ a local complete intersection subscheme of $X \times Y$? Any hint/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: Any closed embedding between non singular varieties is a regular embedding. Thus, $X \to X \times Y$ is a regular embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we need here is smoothness of $Y$. In general if $X$ and $Y$ are varieties over a field $k$, with $Y$ smooth, and if $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism, then $ \Gamma_f \subset X \times Y$ is a local complete intersection, with co-normal bundle isomorphic to $f^* \Omega_Y$.

To see this, note that $\pi_X: X \times Y \to X$ is a smooth morphism (since $Y$ is smooth) and $\mathrm{id} \times f: X \to X \times Y$ gives a section, with image $\Gamma_f$. Since $\Gamma_f$ is certainly smooth over $X$ (the projection $\Gamma_f \to X$ is an isomorphism) a relative version of Hartshorne II.8.17 implies the conormal sequence 
$$
 0 \to \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma_f}/\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma_f}^2 \to \Omega_{X \times Y | X} |_{\Gamma_f} \to \Omega_{\Gamma_f | X} =0 \to 0 
$$ 
is exact. Hence 
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma_f}/\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma_f}^2 \simeq \Omega_{X \times Y | X} |_{\Gamma_f} \simeq (\mathrm{id} \times f)^* \pi_Y^* \Omega_Y \simeq f^* \Omega_Y
$$

Appendix B.7 of Fulton's *Intersection Theory* contains a more detailed discussion, plus some generalizations (l.c.i. morphisms).

Comment: I also found https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/067R helpful!